# Latency Between Amazon Database Server and Web Server Box

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

I am setting up a Magento website with a dedicated box from a major web hosting shop (GoDaddy, HostGator, etc...).  I'll be using Amazon EC2 or RDS for database hosting for easy scale up.  From what I've read, RDS seems to be the preferred choice because of the lower amount of maintenance and administration required.

Will there be a noticeable latency difference between the web server and database server if I host one on Amazon and the other on a different provider?  The servers will be in the same geographic region, but I assume it must be significantly faster if both servers were hosted on the same cluster at a provider.

I've thought about hosting the website on EC2, but would like traditional root access to my box.  I also read that a dedicated box is faster than EC2 when it comes to performance.  Is this true?

This will be a standard e-commerce site; so high number of reads on the DB with much lesser writes to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All EC2 instances are dedicated VPS machines. You have access to root and can install and run just about anything you want.

Because it is virtualized, there is a bit of a hit in terms of performance. This can be problem with certain kinds of workloads. With your workload, probably not. Although it would depend on the kind of traffic you expect to see.

If you do decide to put the web tier and data tier on different providers, you will see a performance impact. This performance impact will be more noticeable, with more queries being run. Using caching can reduce the impact of this. (Using caching is a good idea anyway as the data tier is often harder to scale)